# Statistical match for given n-tuple in set of m n-tuples?

Tags: statistics

I'm having difficulty stating my question, mostly because I have very little statistics training and don't know where to start looking for my answer.

Suppose I have $m$ $n$-tuples. I.e., let $S = \{(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)_i\}_{i=1}^m$. Also let $a = (a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$ be the n-tuple we're trying to "best match" to some $s \in S$. I'm aware that I could loop through $S$, keeping track of the minimum distance from $a$ to $s$.

What I really want, however, is to consider the "best match" when each dimension in the $n$-tuple has a weight, or significance, expressed as $r \in [0, 1]$. E.g., if the first element has weight $1$ and the second has weight $0.2$, and we're trying to match $(1, 0)$ to one of $\{(3, 1), (-0.9, 1.4)\}$, we would rather pick $(-0.9, 1.4)$ even though it's farther from $(1, 0)$ because the first element is what we really care about in this example. So what is the best way to find the "best match?"

EDIT: I think a sufficiently good solution is to minimize $\displaystyle \sqrt{\sum_i r_i (x_i - a_i)^2}$.